# Isomorphism of Groups given by Generators and Defining Equations

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I need help proving that $G$ and $G'$ are isomorphic given $G= Z_2 \times Z_2 \times Z_2 $ and $G'=\{e,a,b,c,ab,ac,bc,abc\}$ where $a^2=b^2=c^2=e$ and $(ab)^2=(bc)^2=(ac)^2=e$

Do I need to show that the elements of $Z_2$ apply to the defining equations of G'? For example $(0,1)^2=(1,0)^2=(1,1)^2=(0,0)=e$ and $((0,1)(1,0))^2=((1,0)(1,1))^2=((0,1)(1,1))^2)=(0,0)=e$

Comment: Wouldn't an element of $G$ be $(0,1)^3$, not $(0,1)^2$?

Comment: @JeremyUpsal I think the correct correction is that he means $(0,1,0)^2$ or something (ordered triples instead of ordered pairs).

Comment: @blf Thanks, this is what I meant as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you can find elements of $G$ that "play the role" of $a$, $b$, $c$, in that they satisfy the defining equations, then that gives you a homomorphism from $G'$ to $G$. Then you just need to show surjectivity.

Comment: I don't see a $d$ in the posted question.

Comment: @coffeemath Thanks! edited.

Comment: I know in the OP problem that $G'$ happens to be commutative (follows from relations). But say $G'$ was just the (nonabelian) group generated by $a,b,c$ with $a^2=b^2=c^2=1$. Then one could find elements in $G$ to map these generators onto, and the map would be also onto if the chosen elements were $(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)$. Then the elements of $G$ would satisfy the defining relations, yet $G$ would not be isomorphic to $G'$.

Comment: @coffeemath but you would need some other relation to specify your group, right?

Comment: I think as soon as generators and relations are specified one automatically has a group. In the nonabelian group $G''$ [using the double prime to distinguish from the $G'$ of the OP] of my comment the element $ab$ has infinite order, and gets mapped to an element of $G$ having of course finite order. I agree one would need more relations if one wanted $G''$ to wind up being isomorphic to the $G$ of OP, but my point was about there being more needed than to map $G''$ to $G$.

Comment: @coffeemath oh of course, I only claimed that this gives you a homomorphism, not an isomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

Prove that the defining equations of $G'$ uniquely determine a single group up to isomorphism. Then all you have to do is show that those defining equations apply to $G$, and you're done.

You can prove that the defining equations uniquely determine one group by writing out the multiplication table for $G'$. You'll notice that the defining equations allow you to deduce the entire table. Hint: start by proving that $a$, $b$ and $c$ are pairwise commutative. From then on it's smooth sailing.